# Get the days in a Week in Javascript, Week starts on Sunday

Tags: javascript, datetime, date, datepicker, dayofweek

Here's the given input from the user:

Year = 2011, Month = 3 (March), Week = 2

I want to get the days in week 2 of March 2011 in JavaScript.

e.g. Sunday 6th, Monday 7th, Tuesday 8th, Wednesday 9th, Thursday 10th, Friday 11th, Saturday 12th

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: How do you define the first week of the month? Is it the week with the first of the month in it? In that case it might also be the last week of the previous month, which might be confusing. In many places, the first day of the week is Monday, not Sunday.

Comment: @RobG "..the first day of the week is Monday, not Sunday.." thats right if we based it on ISO. But it also depends on which country are you living. Most Asian countries begin there week on sundays. I started my week on sunday coz that's what my client told me to do so.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Given

```
var year = 2011;
var month = 3;
var week = 2;
```

and

```
var firstDateOfMonth = new Date(year, month - 1, 1); // Date: year-month-01

var firstDayOfMonth = firstDateOfMonth.getDay();     // 0 (Sun) to 6 (Sat)

var firstDateOfWeek = new Date(firstDateOfMonth);    // copy firstDateOfMonth

firstDateOfWeek.setDate(                             // move the Date object
    firstDateOfWeek.getDate() +                      // forward by the number of
    (firstDayOfMonth ? 7 - firstDayOfMonth : 0)      // days needed to go to
);                                                   // Sunday, if necessary

firstDateOfWeek.setDate(                             // move the Date object
    firstDateOfWeek.getDate() +                      // forward by the number of
    7 * (week - 1)                                   // weeks required (week - 1)
);

var dateNumbersOfMonthOnWeek = [];                   // output array of date #s
var datesOfMonthOnWeek = [];                         // output array of Dates

for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {                        // for seven days...

    dateNumbersOfMonthOnWeek.push(                   // push the date number on
        firstDateOfWeek.getDate());                  // the end of the array

    datesOfMonthOnWeek.push(                         // push the date object on
        new Date(+firstDateOfWeek));                 // the end of the array

    firstDateOfWeek.setDate(
        firstDateOfWeek.getDate() + 1);              // move to the next day

}
```

then

- `dateNumbersOfMonthOnWeek` will have the date numbers of that week.
- `datesOfMonthOnWeek` will have the date objects of that week.

While this may seem like it is overkill for the job, much of this is required to make it work in all situations, like when the date numbers cross over to another month. I'm sure it could be optimised to be less verbose, though.

Comment: that's really good. Can you explain me more about setDate, if thats Ok for you. Sorry I am a beginner of javascript. Thanks a lot.

Comment: `Date::setDate` takes one argument, and that's a 'date number' to change the object's date of the month to. It's smart and useful in the sense that passing it the value `35` will change the date to next month, a few days in, instead of causing an error.

Comment: oh i see, one problem though some week days falls into other months. I'll try to fix it myself. thanks again.

Comment: I have tested my code with situations where some of the resulting days go into the next month. It works.

Comment: Got a problem here, cant find where you put the variable week. I have to change the week dynamically.

Comment: Ah, right. Forgot about that. I'll let you know when I've fixed it.

Comment: Done, I've fixed it now. Does the new code work as you expect?

Comment: Not a problem. Writing this was fun!

Comment: Yeah,  i don't see how this is working... given year = 2014;month = 6;week = 31; dateNumbersOfMonthOnWeek are [28, 29, 30, 31, 1, 2, 3] (ok may not be wrong if the week starts on monday but the next part is really strange) which is wrong and also... datesOfMonthOnWeek gives the for the first 4 dates up to the 31st month December, and the 1,2,3 are in january 2015...

Comment: Ok, the dates for the week are correct, i missed it before, because i was looking at July and the result that was given back is for December...

Answer (score 0):

I normally use [Datejs](http://www.datejs.com/) for date manipulations in js. I'd do it like this:

```
var firstDayOfWeek = new Date(year,month-1,1).moveToDayOfWeek(0,-1).addWeeks(week-1);
var lastDayOfWeek = firstDayOfWeek.addDays(6);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the first week of the month is the one with the first of the month in it, then the following function will return the date of the first day of the week given year, month and week number:

```
/* 
   Input year, month and week number from 1
   Returns first day in week (Sunday) where
   first week is the first with 1st of month in it
*/
function getFirstDayOfWeek(y, m, w) {
  var d = new Date(y, --m);
  d.setDate(--w * 7 - d.getDay() + 1);
  return d;
}

alert(getFirstDayOfWeek(2011,3, 2)); // Sun Mar 06 2011
```

To get the rest of the days, just loop 6 times adding one to the date each time, e.g.

```
function getWeekDates(y, m, w) {
  var d = getFirstDayOfWeek(y, m, w)
  var week = [new Date(d)];
  var i = 6;
  while (i--) {
    week.push(new Date(d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1)));
  }
  return week;
}

// Show week of dates
var week = getWeekDates(2011,3, 2);
for (var i=0, iLen=week.length; i<iLen; i++) {
  alert(week[i]);
}
```

Comment: thanks for you answer robG...im really on a hurry mode now. I wasn't able to check you code.

Comment: @RobG: I have tested your code and met a problem. I also used Console on Chrome to view results. Details:

`Week number: 5
Week: Sun Jan 26 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0700 (SE Asia Standard Time), Mon Jan 27 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0700 (SE Asia Standard Time),..., Sat Feb 01 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0700 (SE Asia Standard Time)

Week number: 6
Week: Sun Mar 02 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0700 (SE Asia Standard Time), Mon Mar 03 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0700 (SE Asia Standard Time),...,Sat Mar 08 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0700 (SE Asia Standard Time)`

There is a problem which from 01/02/2014 (week 5) to 02/03/2014 (week 6). Please fix it.

Answer (score 0):

A little modification of the first answer that worked for me:

```
year = 2014;
week = 31;//week number is 31 for the example, could be 120.. it will just jump trough years
// get the date for the first day of the year               
var firstDateOfYear = new Date(year,0,1);
// set the date to the number of days for the number of weeks
firstDateOfYear.setDate(firstDateOfYear.getDate()+(7 * (week-1))); 
// get the number of the day in the week 0 (Sun) to 6 (Sat)
var counter = firstDateOfYear.getDay();

//make sunday the first day of the week
for(i=0;i<counter;i++){
    firstDateOfYear.setDate(firstDateOfYear.getDate()-1)
}

var firstDateOfWeek = new Date(firstDateOfYear);    // copy firstDateOfYear

var dateNumbersOfMonthOnWeek = [];                   // output array of date #s
var datesOfMonthOnWeek = [];                         // output array of Dates

for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {                        // for seven days...
    dateNumbersOfMonthOnWeek.push(                   // push the date number on
        firstDateOfWeek.getDate());                  // the end of the array

 datesOfMonthOnWeek.push(                         // push the date object on
     new Date(+firstDateOfWeek));                 // the end of the array

 firstDateOfWeek.setDate(
    firstDateOfWeek.getDate() + 1);              // move to the next day
}
```