# Get range of days in a week given a certain day

Tags: c#, date

Suppose my input is `March 31, 2015`.
How would I be able to get the days of the week that `March 31, 2015` is in?
In this case, it should output:
`March 29, 2015`-`April 4, 2015`

I found something similar [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6730246/get-the-days-in-a-week-in-javascript-week-starts-on-sunday) but it's not quite what I'm looking for as that one takes in the week number while my input is a date itself.

Comment: Oops! You're right! Fixed!

Comment: When do you consider the start of the week to be?

Comment: One thing you can do is get the week number with the [`DayOfYear`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.dayofyear(v=vs.110).aspx) `/ 7` then use that solution.

Comment: Perhaps check the `Date.getDay` method, and subtract X from Mar 31st until you get Sunday, then add Y until you get to Saturday?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
DateTime date = new DateTime(2015, 3, 31);
DateTime weekFirstDay = date.AddDays(DayOfWeek.Sunday - date.DayOfWeek);
DateTime weekLastDay = weekFirstDay.AddDays(6);
```

Comment: isnt it `weekLastDay = weekFirstDay.AddDays(7);`

Comment: technically I believe she wants `AddDays(6)` to match her output.  But very efficient answer!

Comment: @Jonesy Yes, just noticed that as well. Thank you :)

Comment: This is excellent! I didn't know about the `DayOfWeek` enumeration. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Here is a way to get each value separately from a given `DateTime`

Week start:

```
    public static DateTime GetWeekStartDate(DateTime value)
    {
        return value.AddDays(-(int)value.DayOfWeek).Date;
    }
```

Week end:

```
    public static DateTime GetWeekEndDate(DateTime value)
    {
        return value.AddDays(6 - (int)value.DayOfWeek).Date;
    }
```

Comment: Did you miss something in your `GetWeekStartDate`? You just have a rogue `-` in `AddDays`

Comment: Nope, that is correct, it turns the `DayOfWeek` `int` value to a negative value.

Comment: OHHHH, duh that makes sense. You want Sunday so if it's Tuesday you're just subtracting that value. Nevermind!

Answer (score 2):

```
DayOfWeek firstDayOfWeek = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek;
DateTime startDate = DateTime.Now;

while (firstDayOfWeek != startDate.DayOfWeek)
{
   startDate = startDate.AddDays(-1);
}

DateTime firstDay = startDate.Date;
DateTime lastDay = startDate.AddDays(6);
```